# youtube subscribe button below video like its a part of video

Tags: wordpress, youtube-api

I see many trending websites use youtube subscribe button as  shown in attached pic. but I am Unable to know how  to use that subscribe button in website[please check the image for more deatails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9htS2.jpg)

here is the html text of story picks that uses same subscribe button

< div class="video-byline">
                    Subscribe to Storypick

Comment: which code  I have to post

Comment: the code of the page with problems...

Comment: I dont have problem with any Page I want subscribe  button like  this link http://www.storypick.com/fevicol-ad-making/ below video

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think you cant understand my Question. Can You know how to apply subscribe button as used by the website whose link i gave you in previous comment.

Comment: check ths source code of that website `<div class="video-byline"> ...` and the the css associate with it.

Comment: please  check  my answer to this post as i posted the  htmlcode

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use this code

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QFu_Kmn3qOk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      // Add code to handle subscribe event.
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>
```

check this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

and you can select a lot of configurations with the button

Hope this helps

take care and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to Storypick

Here it is @Pedro Lobito

Answer (score 0):

```
               <span style="vertical-align:top"> Subscribe to Storypick </span>&nbsp;
               <div id="___ytsubscribe_0" style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 123px; height: 24px; background: transparent;"><iframe frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 123px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 69.1875px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1461955290924" name="I0_1461955290924" src="https://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?usegapi=1&amp;channel=Storypick&amp;layout=default&amp;count=default&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.storypick.com&amp;gsrc=3p&amp;ic=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.HQVJrXyUzfY.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCPsfVIW1uZpDHhPYnkBRXvQcHltAQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&amp;id=I0_1461955290924&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.storypick.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=32575577" data-gapiattached="true"></iframe></div>
            </div>
```

Here it is @Pedro Lobito

Comment: Please update your question, do not post an answer. Delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Subscribe button over [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button).

You can also make your own button, and then link it to the subscription confirmation page, which you can get by appending `?sub_confirmation=1` to your channel URL.: `https://www.youtube.com/channel/your_channel_id?sub_confirmation=1` ([example](https://www.youtube.com/user/googledevelopers?sub_confirmation=1))